# WSO2 tmp directory

Tags: wso2, tmp

**How is it possible to clean tmp directory automatically using WSO2 settings?**

A lot of files are created every day and it would be good to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Could you specify what WSO2 product are you using?

Most WSO2 products has a HouseKeeping property inside carbon.xml config file.

Refer to the documentation of the product you're using to check this property settings:

https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Configuring+carbon.xml